# Windows 10 taskbar - window on different monitor then taskbar icon

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

Hello this is something pretty annoying. I have many windows opened - notepads, several browser windows, Lotus Notes, IM, Total Commander with viewer windows, calculator, several remote desktops, PSPad text editor... And I use two or three monitors. Usually when I move a window from one monitor to another it moves also it's taskbar icon, but sometimes it does not and the icon stays there and does not want to follow it's application's window. Why does this happen? It seems it's the PSPad editor today which refuses to move.

Comment: I assume you have the taskbar setting **Show Taskbar Buttons On** - **Taskbar Where Window is Open**? I've messed around with this a little, and pinning to taskbar can make it act up sometimes.

Comment: yes that's what is there